# How to create a Excel style report with a web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, forms

I've done a fair bit of searching externally and within SO and haven't found something that matches what I'm looking for.

### Explanation

So I created a report within Excel that is filled in by a user(not me), which then automatically emails out to a distro list of people. This is done 6 times a day and is relied on. I have a fair bit of experience with web development and want to move this report to a web page to make things easier on the team, and myself. But I can't really figure out what that would look like. I'm confident it can be done with javascript, but haven't seen anything to this degree.

### Usage

[Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO62B.png)
 | The Excel report takes input like the example image, and copies the table into Outlook.

I'd like to make a form that collects a series of input, formats them into a table that is sent to Outlook, if possible, or outputs something that is able to be copied manually into Outlook. I apologize if this question is confusing, I am still trying to wrap my head around how this would work. Essentially looking for ideas on how to make this work. Scaling it to my needs would be easy once I figure out the base code.

Comment: What should it do more than [Google Sheets](https://www.google.ca/sheets/about/)?

Comment: I'd love to use Google Sheets or one of the many available Form pages, but it needs to be available internally only. I'll be building this website on our internal network so that no data is accessible from outside.